# Absolute Positioning not great with width and left values

Tags: html, css

I have a div with an absolute positioning which is again a child of absolute positioned element. setting width:100%;left:1px;right:1px to the child not working. Problem i face is, its getting beyond the parent the element.

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">

  </div>
</div>
.outer{
    position:absolute;
    width:80px;height:80px;
  border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
 }
.inner{
   position:absolute;
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   background:red;
   left:1px;right:1px;bottom:1px;top:1px
}
```

Refer [here](https://jsfiddle.net/95ptyvtv/)

Answer (score 1):

Just take away the 100% on the child element and the inner div will fit the parent.

```
.outer{
  position:absolute;
  width:80px;height:80px;
  border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
}
.inner{
  position:absolute;
  background:red;
  left:1px;right:1px;bottom:1px;top:1px
}
```

Comment: But width plays a vital role in my code...because I'm actually going to set a background for the inner div based on the divs width

Comment: the width will be 80px - 2px

Comment: Yup width:calc(100%-2px) should do the trick rit...but my concern is my width will be dynamic does calc method will work on dynamic values

Comment: you might run into a perf issue with calc, if you want the width of the inner div work it out with javascript and apply it as an inline styles. If you plan on making it responsive re-apply the width on a resize trigger.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have the width and height to be 100%, meaning it'll be also 80px PLUS the top left right and bottom properties so the box lays over the other. Now if you want it to go inside the box and be perfectly proportioned remove height and width:

```
.inner{
   position:absolute;
   background:red;
   left:1px;right:1px;bottom:1px;top:1px 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also make this:

```css
.outer{
  margin-top: 10px;
  position:absolute;
  width:80px;height:80px;
  border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
  padding: 1px;
}
.inner{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:red;
}
```